# CSS Divs and Text Rotation

Tags: css, html

I've been battling with the following layout and can come close but either my divs are correct and my text is misplaced or vice versa.  Here's what I want, imagine that's a maximized browser...

```
+----------------------------+
|    |#|    |@@@@|    |&|    |
|    |#|    |@@@@|    |&|    |
|    |#|    |@@@@|    |&|    |
|    |#|    |@@@@|    |&|    |
|    |#|    |@@@@|    |&|    |
+----------------------------+
```

The entire page has a white background.  Then I simply need three divs that are colored each the same color, black for example, 100% height.  So in my lame ASCII art drawing, the first div is the "column" filled with '#' symbols, the second div is the column filled with '@' symbols and the third div is the column filled with '&' symbols.

Over the middle column ('@' symbols) I want to layer a piece of text over it that is rotated 270 degrees.  Just a single one line string 10 characters in length, centered vertically and horizontally (or even just horizontally is fine).

Here's my CSS - keep in mind there is junk in here as I went through many renditions before posting.  Again, I can get my divs easy enough but then the text is wrong or if I get the text correct the divs wrong.

```
.container-left
{
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 1px;
        padding: 1px;
        width: 5px;
}

.container-middle
{
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: none;

        display: -ms-flexbox;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;

        display: -moz-box;
        -moz-box-pack: center;
        -moz-box-align: center;

        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;

        display: box;
        box-pack: center;
        box-align: center;
}

.container-right
{
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin: 1px;
        padding: 1px;
        width: 5px;
}
```

My HTML is...

```
<div style='margin: 0 auto;'>
    <div class='container-left'></div>
    <div class='container-middle'>
        <p class='rotate'>This text should be rotated</p>
    </div>
    <div class='container-right'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use float for your containers
2. Make `container-middle` and `p` relative
3. Make text in `p` unbreakable. Calculate `p` position using its width and the width of `container-middle`: p.left = (container.width - p.width) / 2
4. Rotate `p` at origin (50%,50%)

So it ended up like this

http://jsfiddle.net/kTDfH/

Comment: Couple minor tweaks and it works as desired in Safari.  Can you work your magic for Firefox et al?  In FIrefox, the text is out of whack.  Thanks!

Comment: Simple. Add width:160px for p. Remember to recalculate p.left after changing p.width.

Comment: Boom!  Thanks a bunch, layout is great now!